# How to reliably distinguish fetch api rejects?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Is there a clearly defined guide on how to check on what a `fetch` call might **reject** with?

I'm developing an application similar to Postman (or any other api explorer), but without the electron shell, which means I have to rely on what's available in the browser. I would like to clearly distinguish what exactly went wrong when `fetch` rejects.

But browsers seem to reject with completely different messages, for even the most basic stuff. Relying on the error being an `Error` or `TypeError` is not very useful in itself.

For example with my currently installed browsers `fetch`ing a non existing endpoint will result in

- Chrome - `TypeError: Failed to fetch`
- Firefox - `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.`
- Safari - `TypeError: Type error`

Without knowing what other error types there might be, it's duck typing on a whole new level.

So my question is: how exactly could errors be reliably distinguished? Is there any library that "standardizes" errors?

I need to be able to tell the user, that "Your endpoint doesn't exists or the network is down" or "You provided wrong headers, which are wrong for this and that reason".

**Update**
To be clear, with a code example:

```
fetch('...some url...', { /* some args */ })
  .then((response) => {
    // I'm good here, it's clearly documented
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // How do I figure out what EXACTLY went wrong here? 
  })
```

Comment: It will require more digging, but the [`XMLHttpRequest` specification](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/) specifies what kinds of exceptions should be thrown due to various situations (and [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink.git/+/99b8c9800ac123eddc3e199088d22569c5294b22/Source/core/xml/XMLHttpRequest.cpp) you can see Chromium's implementation of them). Maybe there is something in that object that is more precise for what you want to do.